# Plone on ubuntu port 80

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I followed the plone install guide from the [docs](http://docs.plone.org/manage/installing/installation.html).

It goes well and I can access Plone at localhost:8080 . Now I'd like to change the port to 80 so I edit the buildout file, change `http-address = 8080` to `http-address = 80` , build the thing and restart the plone service.

I'd expect to be able to access it now without the :8080 suffix but alas...

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you get nothing at all, or a startup error (`bin/instance fg` will not detach and give you errors on stdout, maybe you already have something blocking port 80)?

Comment: I receive a standard "this webpage is not available". I don't see any errors on the shell. I'm using a newly created ubuntu 12.04 x86 VPS from digital ocean without anything else installed, so port 80 shouldn't be blocked...

Comment: For port 80, you need to run as root; don't do that.  You should not run Plone on port 80 anyway.  Pick a reverse proxy server like Apache httpd, nginx, or varnish on port 80/443, and use that in front of Plone on a TCP port >1024.  All this is very well documented in the standard places.

Comment: Here is an example, how you could configure apache: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443271/how-to-correctly-set-documentroot-in-apache-serving-plone/24445192#24445192

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As sdupton says in the comments, don't do it.

Use Nginx to front it.

See [this link](http://docs.plone.org/manage/deploying/front-end/nginx.html#minimal-nginx-front-end-configuration-for-plone-on-ubuntu-debian-linux) for a how to